# how to display a thumbnail of an image that hasn't been fully loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, networking

I was wondering how to display on client side a thumbnail of an image that hasn't been fully downloaded from a remote server yet.

For example if you send an image to a [whatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com/) contact.. that contact will (almost immediately) see a thumbnail of the image in low rez, and it will start downloading the pic until you see the full res image.

Now one possible scenario is that this process is broken into 4 steps:

1. sender uploads image to whats app server
2. whatApp creates a mini version of the img on the server
3. whatApp sends the mini version of img to receiver, which displays quickly as a low res img, and meanwhile uploads the high res version of the img to the receiver
4. receiver gets the high res image and views it.

what i'm trying to do is create a thumbnail view of all the attachments sent to an email client. There is no server side aspect to my app (it's all client side).. and so I won't be able to replicate the above process (if that were the case with whatsapp)

doing further research, [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) implements a [thumbnail view](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer) of images.. the problem with this library is that each image you instantiate for the thumbnail view must specify a thumbnail URL, which is different from the full sized URL as well (see *@interface MockPhoto* [here](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/samples/TTCatalog/Classes/MockPhotoSource.h) for example ).. so that's a dead end as well..

This [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/progressive-image-rendering.html) about progressive image rendering/interlacing was interesting, but it instructs creators of images to save it in a special way, which won't help me.

any ideas? Maybe there is a library that electively fetches information from an image via a network call?

Comment: So you have the attachments, or you generate the attachments ?

Comment: the attachments are all stored in an imap server.. (let's just say server side.. since i don't think imap changes anything).. so no i don't generate attachments.. i fetch them from the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEGs (optionally) have thumbnails (in the header). However, if you can't control how the images are saved, then you can't make use of this, or, as you mentioned, progressive JPEG images. Besides, with IMAP and POP, you won't have access to individual attachments.

If these images are stored server side, then you can generate thumbnails using a server-side image library.

However, if this is a client-side email app, where you don't control the server, then you are pretty much out of luck. You won't be able to do anything until you download the message attachments. The only exception would be if the email server had some kind of API you could tie into (or has a custom IMAP extension).

The POP and IMAP protocols do not have any feature built in for thumbnails. Perhaps an Outlook mail server has something?

Comment: Even if the outlook server thingie were true, unfortunately I can't implement any vendor/service-provider specific libraries/modules.. i want my email client to be vendor agnostic (unless of course, if gmail/google has something to offer.. then maybe i can deploy gmail only at the beginning then go from there.. like how mailbox did)

Answer (score 1):

You kinda answered your own question already with the way you broke it down. I have a very similar structure in one of my apps. I wrote something like iMessage/WhatsApp (for educational purposes).

1) Person A sends the image to the server.

2) The server creates a thumbnail from the image.

3) Person B first downloads (in the background) the thumbnail which is almost instantaneous because it is only a couple of K in size.

4) Once the thumbnail is downloaded, the full size image is downloaded (in the background).

If the Person B selects the thumbnail before the full size image has completed downloading, I have a "loading..." text in place of the image.

BUT... unless you have good reason to download the full image automatically, I would suggest you only start downloading it if the user wants to see the full image. Why waste bandwidth on something that the user might or might not want to see. Also remember to use compression whenever you can.

Comment: JPEG images are already compressed (lossy). You generally won't get any improvement from further compressing them with a lossless compression, and often quite the opposite.

Comment: I beg to differ. I usually compress my images enough to save at least 50% file size while keeping the image quality within acceptable limits. But again, it all comes down to what the end product will be used for.

Comment: I think you may be talking about compression ratio (often labeled "quality"). It seems odd to remind someone to use compression on a file format (JPEG) that automatically uses compression.